# Pandas - compute previous custom quarter wise total revenue and reshape table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a dataframe like as below

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'stud_id' : [101, 101, 101, 101, 
                  101, 102, 102, 102],
     'sub_code' : ['CSE01', 'CSE01', 'CSE01', 
                   'CSE01', 'CSE02', 'CSE02',
                   'CSE02', 'CSE02'],
     'ques_date' : ['10/11/2022', '06/06/2022','09/04/2022', '27/03/2022', 
                '13/05/2010',  '10/11/2021','11/1/2022', '27/02/2022'],
     'revenue' : [77, 86, 55, 90, 
                65, 90, 80, 67]}
)
df['ques_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ques_date'])
```

I would like to do the below

a) Compute custom quarter based on our organization FY calendar. Meaning, Oct-Dec is Q1, Jan -Mar is Q2,Apr - Jun is Q3 and July to Sep is Q4.

b) Group by stud_id

c) Compute sum of revenue from previous two quarters (from a specific date = 20/12/2022). For example, if we are in `2023Q1`, I would like to get the sum of revenue for a customer from `2022Q4` and `2022Q3` seperately

So, I tried the below

```
df['custom_qtr'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ques_date'], dayfirst=True).dt.to_period('Q-SEP')
date_1 = pd.to_datetime('20-12-2022')
df['date_based_qtr']  = date_1.to_period('Q-SEP')
pat = '(Q(\d+))'
df['custom_qtr_number'] = df['custom_qtr'].astype(str).str.extract(pat, expand=False)[1]
df['date_qtr_number'] = df['date_based_qtr'].astype(str).str.extract(pat, expand=False)[1]
```

But am not sure, how to reshape the dataframe and get an output like below. You can see that we are `2023Q1` and I would like to get the `sum of revenue from previous two quarters seperately`. Meaning, revenue from 2022Q4 and 2022Q3 respectively

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2 previous quarters subtract `date_based_qtr` by `custom_qtr` with converting to integers and test membership by `1,2`, last pivoting:

```
df['ques_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ques_date'])
df['custom_qtr'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ques_date'], dayfirst=True).dt.to_period('Q-SEP')
date_1 = pd.to_datetime('20-12-2022')
df['date_based_qtr']  = date_1.to_period('Q-SEP')

df = df[df['date_based_qtr'].sub(df['custom_qtr']).apply(lambda x: x.n).isin([1,2])]

df = df.pivot(['stud_id','date_based_qtr'],'custom_qtr','revenue')
print (df)
custom_qtr              2022Q3  2022Q4
stud_id date_based_qtr                
101     2023Q1              86      55
```

Comment: I see that you used pivot here. Let's say if some `stud_id` have zero revenue in previous two quarters, will those records show up as zeroes (for `2022Q3 and 2022Q4`).  Does pivot also work like `left merge` where records that don't have a match will return 0.

Comment: I updated my input sample

Comment: @TheGreat - Can you change data sample for this error?

Comment: I removed the duplicate index error. Please find the code below what am trying to do in my original data - `t2 = t1.pivot_table('Revenue',
                     index=['unique_key','stud_id','MainCustomer','Sales_Product'],
                     columns=['date_based_qtr'],
                     aggfunc='sum')`

Comment: Above comment, tried to do `sum` of `revenue` for each group (of `unique_key, stud_id, MainCustomer, Sales Prodicy`. But this doesn't work for the real data

Comment: Since each stud_id, may have multiple revenue records for the same `custom_qtr`, we use `aggfunc` to perform sum of revenue.

Comment: You can ignore duplicate index error for now

Comment: @TheGreat - `pivot_table` instead `pivot` cannot be used? This is way for remove this error.  `But this doesn't work for the real data` - can you explain more?

Comment: I have given an example here for another issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74917129/pandas-compute-and-pivot-to-get-revenue-from-previous-two-years