# Pandas - compute and pivot to get revenue from previous two years

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot-table

I have a dataframe like as below

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'stud_id' : [101, 101, 101, 101, 
                  101, 102, 102, 102],
     'sub_code' : ['CSE01', 'CSE01', 'CSE01', 
                   'CSE01', 'CSE02', 'CSE02',
                   'CSE02', 'CSE02'],
     'ques_date' : ['10/11/2022', '06/06/2022','09/04/2022', '27/03/2022', 
                '13/05/2010',  '10/11/2021','11/1/2022', '27/02/2022'],
     'revenue' : [77, 86, 55, 90, 
                65, 90, 80, 67]}
)
df['ques_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ques_date'])
```

I would like to do the below

a) Compute custom financial year based on our organization FY calendar. Meaning, Oct-Dec is Q1, Jan -Mar is Q2,Apr - Jun is Q3 and July to Sep is Q4.

b) Group by stud_id

c) Compute sum of revenue from previous two custom FYs (from a specific date = 20/12/2022). For example, if we are in the FY-2023, I would like to get the sum of revenue for a customer from FY-2022 and FY-2021 separately

So, I tried the below based on this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74860835/pandas-compute-previous-custom-quarter-wise-total-revenue-and-reshape-table)

```
df['custom_qtr'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ques_date'], dayfirst=True).dt.to_period('Q-SEP')
date_1 = pd.to_datetime('20-12-2022') # CUT-OFF DATE
df['custom_year'] = df['custom_qtr'].astype(str).str.extract('(?P<year>\d+)')
df['date_based_qtr']  = date_1.to_period('Q-SEP')
df['custom_date_year'] = df['date_based_qtr'].astype(str).str.extract('(?P<year>\d+)')
df['custom_year'] = df['custom_year'].astype(int)
df['custom_date_year'] = df['custom_date_year'].astype(int)
df['diff'] = df['custom_date_year'].sub(df['custom_year'])
df = df[df['diff'].isin([1,2])]
out_df = df.pivot_table("revenue", index=['stud_id'],columns=['custom_year'],aggfunc=['sum']).add_prefix('rev_').reset_index().droplevel(0,axis=1)
```

But this results in an inconcistent output column like below

[image]

I expect my output to be like as below

[image]

**updated output**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you just need to first fine the quarter year, filter to only include 2021 and 2022 rows, and then summarize & pivot:

```
(df.assign(
    qyear = pd.to_datetime(df['ques_date'], dayfirst=True).dt.to_period('Q-SEP').dt.qyear
  )[lambda x: x.qyear.isin([2021, 2022])]
  .assign(qyear=lambda x: x.qyear.astype('category').cat.set_categories([2021, 2022]))
  .groupby(['stud_id', 'qyear'])
  .revenue.sum()
  .unstack(level=1)
  .add_prefix('rev_')
  .reset_index(drop=False))

#qyear  stud_id  rev_2021  rev_2022
#0          101         0       231
#1          102         0       157
```

For the update:

```
df['qyear'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ques_date'], dayfirst=True).dt.to_period('Q-SEP').dt.qyear.astype('category').cat.set_categories([2021, 2022])
df.groupby(['stud_id', 'sub_code', 'qyear']).revenue.sum().unstack(level=1, fill_value=0).add_prefix('rev_').reset_index(drop=False)

sub_code  stud_id qyear  rev_CSE01  rev_CSE02
0             101  2021          0          0
1             101  2022        231          0
2             102  2021          0          0
3             102  2022          0        157
```

Comment: nice. but how do we drop the `qyear` column in your output? When I set `reset_index(drop=True)`, it drops the `stud_id` column. But I wish to drop `qyear` column from the shown output

Comment: `qyear` is just a display name for the columns object. It's not a real column. If you capature the output of above as `_df` and then `_df.columns.name = None`. It will be gone.

Comment: there is one issue though. When I use multiple columns in `groupby` statment, I get the columns names are messed up. Meaning, it takes suffix of other groupby columns

Comment: refer the post above for updated screenshot of output. Moreover the `sub_code` is not coming up in the output shown above (even though it is used in groupby)

Comment: Instead of just `stud_id`, I grouped them using `stud_id, sub_code`. So, even if we add multiple columns under groupby, the output column names should only be `rev_2022 and rev_2021`.

Comment: It should be similar. See the update -

Comment: hmm. I think it is still incorrect. You can see that in your ouptut, even though you use `sub_cod` column in your groupby statement, it is not shown in the output. Instead, they come up as column names. If there are more `sub_code` in the data, then output will be messed up. elenogated with seperate columns for each sub_code. But we should only have `rev_2022` and `rev_2021` in the column (along with group by columns)